# how to name jquery javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I name the following so I can call it besides when the A tag is clicked:

```
$(function(myMessage) {
  $('.my-link').click(function() {
    alert(myMessage);
    return false
  });
});
```

Something like call:
     callMyMessage(myMessage);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare it, giving it a name, and then use that name:

```
$(function(myMessage) {
  // Declaration
  function functionNameHere() {
    alert(myMessage);
    return false
  }

  // Use as handler
  $('.my-link').click(functionNameHere);

  // Other use
  functionNameHere();
});
```

---

In a comment below you've said:

> I want to call this from a jquery post in another js file

To do that, you have to make it accessible outside the `ready` handler. I automatically scoped it just to that handler because I hate creating globals.

Here's the change:

```
// Declaration
function functionNameHere() {
  alert(myMessage);
  return false
}

$(function(myMessage) {

  // Use as handler
  $('.my-link').click(functionNameHere);

  // Other use
  functionNameHere();
});
```

Now, code in other script files loaded on the page can also call it (the way shown near the end, `functionnameHere();`).

Comment: so to call this from another function I would just use functionNameHere() ?

Comment: I want to call this from a jquery post in another js file.

Comment: @Atma: If you want access to the function from outside the `ready` handler above, you have to move it. I've updated the answer to show you how.

Comment: When I call functionNameHere() from a jquery document $(document).ready i get the error that functionNameHere is undefined.  I include the js file right before calling the function.  Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @Atma: No, no idea I'm afraid. If the function is declared a global scope (as shown above), and the script declaring it is above the script trying to use it in the HTML, then the function *will* exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a named function.
You can then add that function as a click handler:

```
$(...).click(someFunction);
```

Comment: He can also do `$('.my-link').trigger('click')` if what he's really asking is how to trigger the event without user interaction.